# APache2 http -> https forwarding

Tags: debian, apache2, http-redirect, apache-config

I am stuck with forwarding http to https requests in Apache2:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www
       Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
    </VirtualHost>
    
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
      ServerName example.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www
      SSLEngine On
     # etc...
    </VirtualHost>
```

The site is available at `https://example.com/mysite` but if I enter `http://example.com/mysite`, I get forwarded to `https://example.com/mysitemysite` (note the mysitemysite instead of mysite in the end).

What do I need to change in the config file to prevent that issue?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Redirect permanent to achieve https, you should use a Rewrite rule.
Replace your code with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  SSLEngine On
 # etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

Here we're using a Rewrite rule to activate your website SSL.

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [R,L]
```

And make sure that you have Rewrite module enabled in your apache.
To enable the modrewrite, access the apache2 module directory `cd /etc/apache2/mods-available` run the following command `a2enmod rewrite.load` and restart your apache2 `service apache2 restart`